# How can I manipulate the solution of my differential equation into a nice form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\left(2P^{2}-P\right)\cos t$$
I can simply integrate both sides to obtain $$\frac{\left(2P-1\right)^{2}}{P}=ke^{\frac{1}{2}\sin t}$$ I have troubles from here on. I need to separate it to be in terms of a single $P$, and I've tried completing the square, quadratic formula (after timesing up the $P$), and squaring both sides. What should I do? A hint would be nice

Also $k = 1$ ( from the initial value problem in the original question ), although I dont think that matters too much.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing how you obtained the LHS of your equation after your supposed integration. Shouldn't the denominator be $P^2$?

Comment: That's not what I get when I solve, the left hand side should be $$1-\frac{1}{2P}$$

Comment: I got $$
\frac{{2P - 1}}{P} = ke^{\frac{1}{2}\sin t}
$$ after integration.

Comment: @EthanMark right idea wrong term. From the right hand side we can see the square root was already taken

Comment: @NinadMunshi I am doing this on the move so it's all mental sums for me right now. Basically I believe his LHS is wrong.

Comment: @Gary the original ODE factors $P\left(P-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: Yes Gary my LHS was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your differential equation is correct, then $$\frac 1 {P(2P - 1)}\mathrm{d}P = \frac 1 2 \cos t\ \mathrm{d}t$$

and we further decompose the LHS using partial fractions into $$\left(\frac 2 {2P - 1} - \frac 1 P\right)\mathrm{d}P = \frac 1 2 \cos t\ \mathrm{d}t.$$

Integrating both sides, we have $$\ln (2P - 1) - \ln P = \frac 1 2 \sin t + C, C \in \mathbb {R}$$

Now, we perform some magic (i.e. algebraic manipulation).

$$\ln \frac {(2P - 1)} P = \frac 1 2 \sin t + C$$

$$\frac {(2P - 1)} P = ke^{\frac 1 2 \sin t}, k \in \mathbb {R}$$

$$2 - \frac 1 P = ke^{\frac 1 2 \sin t}$$

$$\frac 1 P = 2 - ke^{\frac 1 2 \sin t}$$

Finally, $$P = \frac 1 {2 - ke^{\frac 1 2 \sin t}}$$ which is as nice as it gets.

**Comments**

You probably did not get this right as your integration was incorrect to begin with. However, you are right that the value of $k$ is irrelevant if all you are concerned with is making $P$ the subject of the formula.

Comment: In line 3, why is it not $2(\ln{(2P-1)})$?

Comment: Nevermind I see.

Answer (score 1):

You get
$$\int \frac{dp}{2p^2-p}=\frac{1}{2} \int \cos t~dt \implies \ln \frac{2p-1}{p}=\frac{1}{2} \sin t+ c$$
$$\implies 2-\frac{1}{p}=ke^{\frac{1}{2}\ln \sin t}\implies p= \frac{1}{2-ke^{\frac{1}{2}\sin t}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $U=2-P^{-1}$, $U(0)=2-P(0)^{-1}=1$, then you get
$$
U'=P^{-2}P'=\frac12(2-P^{-1})\cos t=\frac{U}2\cos t
$$
and consequently
$$
U(t)=U(0)e^{\sin(t)/2}
$$
Now solve backward
$$
2-P(t)^{-1}=e^{\sin(t)/2}.
$$